# If (a, b) = d, then (a/d, b/d) = 1

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Proof.

Let c = (a/d, b/d).
Then c | a/d, and so cd | a.
Also c | b/d, and so cd | b.

My question is, did this happen because of this simple algebra?
ie.  c | a/d
     So  cx = a/d  for some integer x
     then  cx/d = a

Next step of proof..
Thus, cd is a common divisor of a and b.
Therefore, cd <= d, which implies c = 1.

My question for this part:  how did I conclude cd <= d?

Comment: Pardon me, i am still trying to learn how to use correct format.

Answer (score 1):

If $cd$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$, it is a divisor of the greatest common divisor, which is $d$. Hence $cd|d$.

Remark:

If you are familiar with Bezout's identity.

We have $$ax+by=d, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$x\left( \frac{a}d\right)+ y\left( \frac{b}d\right)=1$$

and we can conclude.

Comment: Sorry sir, i am not familiar with Bezout’s identity. Can this be done without that knowledge?

Comment: $cd$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$, it can't be larger than the greatest common divisor, hence $cd \le d$. btw, in your working $cx=\frac{a}d$, the next line should be $cxd=a$ rather than dividing by $d$.